# The correct way to document a tagged version using README.org at GitHub

Tags: github, git-tag, readme

I document my software using the `README.org` file, which is rendered nicely in the master branch in GitHub. Now, suppose I create a tag `v1.0` and want to share a link to that tagged version with others. Unfortunately, when one follows that link, he does not find my `README.org` nicely rendered, but only the archived code. So, what is the correct way of documenting a tagged version at GitHub? (of course, I am looking to re-use my `README.org`).

Comment: Could you add a link to the problematic repository? READMEs seem correctly rendered in the "tag" view for some repos, e.g. [d3-selection's README.md](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/tree/v1.3.1), or [Vim Org Mode's README.org](https://github.com/jceb/vim-orgmode/tree/v0.5.0)

Comment: @MehdiElFadil Thank you! Your links helped me figure out the problem. I linked to `.../releases/tag/v1.0` instead of `.../tree/v1.0`.